# How to create a radio button group component with vue3 and vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Using Vue3 and Vuetify to create a yes/no radio button component.

I get this error with the below code `Unexpected mutation of "selectedValue" prop.`
I understand that props aren't supposed to be changed but can't understand how to implement something like this.

`YesNoRadioButton.vue`

```
<template>
    <v-radio-group inline :label=title v-model=selectedValue>
        <v-radio label="Yes" :value=true></v-radio>
        <v-radio label="No" :value=false></v-radio>
    </v-radio-group>
</template>

<script setup>
import { defineProps } from 'vue'

defineProps({
    title: String,
    selectedValue: Boolean
})

</script>
```

`Parent.vue`

```
<template>
    <YesNoRadioButton title="Are You Sure?" :selectedValue=userAnswer />
</template>

<script setup>
    import  YesNoRadioButton from './YesNoRadioButton.vue'
    const userAnswer = ref(true);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `v-model` in the parent on the `<YesNoRadioButton />` element, then, following the [Vue documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html#component-v-model) on setting a v-model on a custom component, the child component needs to receive the v-model as a prop. This prop should be bound to the `<v-radio-group>` (1-way binding, **not** as v-model), and then the radio-group should emit it's updated value to the parent which will complete the two-way binding between parent v-model and the radio-group.

**Parent.vue**

```
<template>
  <YesNoRadioButton title="Are You Sure?" v-model="userAnswer" />
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue'
  import YesNoRadioButton from './YesNoRadioButton.vue'

  const userAnswer = ref(true)
</script>
```

**YesNoRadioButton.vue**

```
<template>
  <v-radio-group
    inline
    :label="title"
    :model-value="modelValue"
    @update:modelValue="$emit('update:modelValue', $event)"
  >
    <v-radio label="Yes" :value="true"></v-radio>
    <v-radio label="No" :value="false"></v-radio>
  </v-radio-group>
</template>

<script setup>
  defineProps({
    title: String,
    modelValue: Boolean,
  })
  defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])
</script>
```

[Vuetify Playground example](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I need to read up more on the event emitted part but this all makes more sense now.